# Localization issue - Windows 8.1 App

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8.1

I am having trouble changing my app's language. The language should be changed when the user changes the selected item in a combobox.

Here's a snippet of a part of my code:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {        
       ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView().QualifierValues.MapChanged += QualifierValues_MapChanged;

    }

private void QualifierValues_MapChanged(IObservableMap<string, string> sender, IMapChangedEventArgs<string> @event)
    {
        ResourceContext.ResetGlobalQualifierValues();
    }
```

The combobox code is:

```
private void cbLanguage_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0 && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(((ComboBoxItem)e.AddedItems[0]).Tag as string))
        {
            LocalizationManager.UICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo((string)((ComboBoxItem)e.AddedItems[0]).Tag);
            Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = LocalizationManager.UICulture.Name;
            int index = 0;
            if (cbLanguage.SelectedIndex == 0 || cbLanguage.SelectedIndex < 0)
            {
                index = cbLanguage.Items.Count - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                index = cbLanguage.SelectedIndex - 1;
            }

            Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = (string)((ComboBoxItem)cbLanguage.Items[index]).Tag as String;
            Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = ((ComboBoxItem)e.AddedItems[0]).Tag as String;

            if (languageChange != null)
            {
                languageChange(sender, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            LocalizationManager.UICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
        }
    }
```

This returns an access violation error.

Could you please help me out so the app changes language correctly?

Comment: I've tried running this code but the function 'MapChanged' is not called. Could you share the code for the combobox? Maybe that will help me recreate your issue.

Comment: Hi @BryanStump,

I've updated the post with combobox code. Thanks for trying to help me out.

FYI, the code I had for Windows 8 app worked absolutely fine. This happened when I targeted the app to Windows 8.1.

Comment: I ran the code and could not reproduce the error. Without the Localation manager class and knowing which Tags are on the combo box items it's possible the error is there.

Comment: @BryanStump, what confuses me is that the app worked fine when it was targeted to Windows 8, but after targeting to Windows 8.1 it stopped working.

Comment: The bug isn't in this code, as I can run it without error. What are the Tags in the combo box items? Could you use a try{}catch{}?

Comment: I forgot to add, the code doesn't reach the breakpoint for the MapChanged handler. Please provide more sample code that so that I can reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

The code is setting the `Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride` three times. What is the reason for this?

After setting the primay language, why change the index and set the language again?

```
if (cbLanguage.SelectedIndex == 0 || cbLanguage.SelectedIndex < 0)
        {
            index = cbLanguage.Items.Count - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            index = cbLanguage.SelectedIndex - 1;
        }
```